# Unable to locate nested geopoint after updating to elasticsearch 2.3

Tags: python, elasticsearch, elasticsearch-dsl

We use the AWS managed Elasticsearch service and recently upgraded from 1.5 to 2.3. We use the elasticsearch-dsl package in python to build our queries and managed to migrate most of our queries, but geo_distance is broken no matter what I try.

Mapping:

```
{
        'company': {
            'properties': {
                'id': {'type': 'integer'},
                'company_number': {'type': 'string'},
                'addresses': {
                    'type': 'nested',
                    'properties': {
                        'postcode': {'type': 'string', 'index': 'not_analyzed'},
                        'location': {'type': 'geo_point'}
                    }
                }
             }
        }
}
```

Python code working with elasticsearch-dsl==0.0.11

```
            test_location = '53.5411062377, -2.11485504709'
            test_distance = "3miles"
            location_filter = F("geo_distance", 
                                location=test_location,
                                distance=test_distance)
            query = query.filter("nested", 
                                 path="addresses",
                                 filter=location_filter)
```

Query generated by the library:

```
{'query': {'filtered': {'filter': {'nested': {'filter': {'geo_distance': {'distance': u'3miles', 'location': '53.5411062377, -2.11485504709'}}, 'path': 'addresses'}}, 'query': {'match_all': {}}}}}
```

We have created a brand new index on a new 2.3 with the same mapping.

After updating to elasticsearch-dsl == 2.1.0 and attempting to convert the filters to queries:

```
geo_query = Q({"bool": {
                    "must": [
                        {
                            "geo_distance": {
                                "distance": "test_distance",
                                "addresses__location": test_location,
                            }
                        },
                    ]
                }})
```

That generates the following query:

```
{'query': {'bool': {'must': [{'geo_distance': {'distance': '3 miles', u'addresses.location': {'lat': '53.5411062377', 'lon': '-2.11485504709'}}}]}}}
```

We get the following exception:

```
RequestError: TransportError(400, u'search_phase_execution_exception', u'failed to find geo_point field [addresses.location]')
```

I tried referencing the field as 'location' , 'addresses.location', 'addresses' and using the old nested query type. I can't figure out if the mapping is no longer valid in  2.3 or if I am constructing the query wrong.

The query

```
Q({'nested': {'filter': {
                        'geo_distance': {'distance': u'3miles', 'location': '53.5411062377, -2.11485504709'}
                    },
                    'path': 'addresses.location'}})
```

Generates the following error:

```
RequestError: TransportError(400, u'search_phase_execution_exception', u'[nested] nested object under path [addresses.location] is not of nested type')
```

I think I need to add lat_lon : True to the mapping for geodistance queries to work, but none of the examples have it.

Any help would be very much appreciated, thank you!

Comment: `path` must be `addresses`  and in the `geo_distance` filter you must have `"addresses.location"` instead of just `"location"`

Comment: Sorry I have tried that, along with '.location'.

Comment: Can you try the answer below?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should work:

```
        test_location = '53.5411062377, -2.11485504709'
        test_distance = "3miles"
        location_query = Q("geo_distance", 
                            addresses__location=test_location,
                            distance=test_distance)
        query = query.filter("nested", 
                             path="addresses",
                             query=location_query)
```

Comment: Will give this a try as soon as I can!

Comment: let me know if that still doesn't work, and we'll figure it out

Comment: This seems to have worked, even though I could have sworn I have tried it already! I thought the root of the issue was not sending the mapping correctly when recreating the index, but either way it is working now. Thank you very much for spending time on my problem!